# Convert a .md file back to .Rmd

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio

Perhaps a simple question, but I was wondering if there was a function that would reconvert `.md` files back to the `.Rmd` file that originally created it, as I seem to have lost my original `.Rmd` file and would rather not just copy and paste the code sections. The `.md` file was originally created using the `knit` to html function in RStudio.

Comment: Could you provide a small example `.md` file? In this way we could suggest some options.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a tool that does this out of the box. However, you could probably use a combination of the linux command line tools `grep` and `sed` to get the desired effect. I think this could be quite a lot of work to get working in a general sense, so copy/pasting in your case would be the fastest way.

Comment: Note that if some chunks have been run with `echo = F` or `include = F`, it will not be able to find the code from these chunks,

Comment: @mnel I wonder if it can be inferred from the `.md`, or perhaps it could generate as best it can and warn that it had to sensibly guess?